# Using Pro Micro without soldering pin

Tags: arduino-micro

I'm a total newbie. I bought a Pro Micro but I didn't know that it can't be used, if you don't solder things in his holes.
I found this picture on Google:[image]

And it seems that exists those stuffs (green and white) to test the circuit before soldering.

Do you know where can I buy them? Or do you know their name?

Thanks.

Comment: As alternative I am looking for screws that would fit the pins but i've still haven't found any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for items [like these](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2617) from from a well established seller adafruit.com.  However, what you are proposing is not cheap when compared to soldering.  I would recommend you [learn soldering](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-guide-excellent-soldering/tools) as it will likely be the way you want to assemble your final Arduino project.

Comment: It's exactly what I looking for! Yes, sooner or later I'll learn how to solder. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just getting started and are not comfortable with soldering I would suggest getting one of the larger boards that has headers on it. (An Uno or a Mega, for example). You can use one of those and a breadboard to experiment without having to solder at all.

MicroCenter (A US retailer) sells 100% compatible Arduino Mega 2560 knockoffs for $10 US.

I suggest using a board like that when you are first starting out. (And learn how to solder. It's very useful for electronics repair and various other things.)

Comment: I need a Pro Micro because I need its ability to emulate an HID USB device.